# How to define a function to decouple equations and transform them into standard form

Tags: equation-solving

I want to convert this expression($\frac{x-a 2}{a 1}=\frac{y-b 2}{b 1}=\frac{z-c 2}{c 1}$) of the linear equation into a standard form  $\left\{\begin{matrix}
\text { b1 } * x-a 1 * y=a 2 * b 1-a 1 * b 2\\
\text { c1 } * y-b 1 * z=b 2 * c 1-b 1 * c 2 \\
\text { c1 } * x-a 1 * z=a 2 * c 1-a 1 * c 2
\end{matrix}\right.$

```
(x - a2)/a1 == (y - b2)/b1 == (z - c2)/c1
```

What can I do to quickly decouple $\frac{x-a 2}{a 1}=\frac{y-b 2}{b 1}=\frac{z-c 2}{c 1}$ into the following desired format?

```
{b1*x - a1*y == a2*b1 - a1*b2,
 c1*y - b1*z == b2*c1 - b1*c2,
 c1*x - a1*z == a2*c1 - a1*c2}
```

Comment: You can quickly get them into an ==0 form if that interests you too. `eqns = (x - a2)/a1 == (y - b2)/b1 == (z - c2)/c1; neweqns = #*Denominator[#] == 0 & /@ Together[(Subsets[eqns, {2}]) /. Equal -> Subtract]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eqns = (x - a2)/a1 == (y - b2)/b1 == (z - c2)/c1;
vars = {x, y, z};

(* break up into pairwise equations and subtract rhs - lhs *)
pairwise = (Subsets[eqns, {2}]) /. Equal -> Subtract;

(* eliminate fractions *)
nofrac = #*Denominator[#] & /@ Together[pairwise]

(* move terms involving variables onto lhs and put constant terms on right *)
Total[Most[#]] == If[FreeQ[Last[#], Alternatives@@vars], -Last[#], 0] & /@ 
 (MonomialList[#, vars] & /@ nofrac)

(* result:
 {b1 x - a1 y == a2 b1 - a1 b2,
  c1 x - a1 z == a2 c1 - a1 c2, 
  c1 y - b1 z == b2 c1 - b1 c2} *)
```

That last part could be simplified a bit using `CoefficientArrays`:

```
#[[2]].vars == -#[[1]] & /@ (CoefficientArrays[#, vars] & /@ nofrac)
```